# Can I interrupt installation process with preflight function?

Tags: joomla-3.x, jinstaller

I'm trying to add a note to user when trying to install an extension / module.

Basically I want to add note before user continuing the module installation process when an older version found, and they can continue the installation process by clicking a button.

Is it possible to do that with [preflight function](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file)? If it's possible how can I do that?

Comment: More info about what would you like to handle that way? Like question about old settings or what?

Comment: I mean anything is possible but pausing the install process of an extension is not a common practice in Joomla. However it could be solved of course.

Comment: Hi @Zollie, yes exactly like you said. I'd like to tell the user that they need to re-visit the module setting page and re-saving that page, because of some major changes, some options are no longer availabe, replaced by the new ones. If they are sure about it then they can continue the installation process, otherwise they can cancel

Comment: @webchun can you show us precisely how far you've progressed before getting stuck? When you do this, you narrow your issue and make answering easier and more attractive.  Right now, your question is seeking a complete tutorial, but hopefully you only require a partial tutorial.  Show us whatcha got.